# Inequality Subsetting in data.table - Binary Searching

Tags: r, data.table, binary-search

I'm having an issue getting a subset in data.table to run quickly. Suppose we have a data set with a column "keyCol", and we want the sub-set where keyCol == 2. As I understand it, typically, the most efficient subset is something along the lines of:

```
setkey(dt, keyCol)
dt[.(2)]
```

This is the keyed binary search method that data.table is really good for. But, how do I implement this for an inequality? Is there a method of keying a table such that ineqaulity searches can be as efficient as equality searches? If we wanted, for example, the sub-set where keyCol > 4:

```
dt[keyCol > 4]
```

.... but this is not quite fast enough for my purposes. So is there a way to do this? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the nature of keyed binary searching? Any input would be great.

Thanks

EDIT: The exact problem I'm trying to solve is the following. I have a dataset with columns Date, id, and group., I'm trying to find how many of the id's change group over some Date horizon. So my data for a particular id looks like:

```
Date          id          Group
2018-01-01    A           1
2018-02-01    A           2
2018-03-01    A           1
2018-04-01    A           3
2018-05-01    A           5
2018-06-01    A           1
```

I want to find the old group that they were in at some variable "lag" ago, so I create a new column called oldGroup:

```
dt[, oldGroup := Group - c(rep(NA, lag), diff(Group, lag = lag)), id]
```

So if the lag is 1 (i.e. we want to know the group from 1 period ago, we would get:

```
Date          id          Group          oldGroup
2018-01-01    A           1              NA
2018-02-01    A           2              1
2018-03-01    A           1              2
2018-04-01    A           3              1
2018-05-01    A           5              3
2018-06-01    A           1              5
```

The issue with this is that there are some id's who have less data points than the lag parameter. In other words there may only be 5 data points but we want lag = 6. This will throw an error during the assignment of oldGroup. To solve this I'm using an inequality beforehand like so:

```
dt[, occurences := .N, id]
dt <- dt[occurences > lag]
```

This way no errors are thrown, but the subset takes over a second, which, although it isn't very long, I'd like to make faster.

I hope this explains the issue. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: As a rule of thumb - if the simple subset is "not fast enough" - you're doing something wrong *before* you get there. I'd suggest posting the bigger picture problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I explained more thoroughly.

Comment: Generally, group IDs do not have arithmetic done on them (your `oldGroup := Group - shift(Group, lag)`), so I'm still not following... anyway, fyi, see `?shift` if you don't want to fiddle with how lagging works depending on # data points.

Comment: what Frank said about using `shift`; also do `dt[, if (.N > lag) .SD, id]` instead

Comment: shift was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Frank!